Is there a way to undo all the sorting and editing done on a google form response spreadsheet?
My colleague and I did a survey on google form. Once the data started coming in, she started sorting and editing the data directly on the response spreadsheet. This led to the data getting mixed up. I only realized the results were wrong after analyzing the data, and there was no way the respondents could have provided their answers wrong.
Questions:

Is this caused by the filtering, sorting and editing data directly in the google form response spreadsheet?
Is there a way to undo all the sorting, filtering and editing, so that we see only the original response from all the respondents?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

If you did all the sorting AFTER the last response, you can access to the Version History in  File>Version Historyor withCtrl.+Alt+Shift+H`

There you can check, recover or make a copy of the prior versions of the spreadsheet. If you did the editions after the last response, just find the moment of the last response, and recover that; if you made editions in between responses, it would be a little trickier to track down the responses
But, what you can do is to Unlink your form:

And create a new file, by selecting a new destination in the Responses tab of the form:

It would create a new fresh spreadsheets with all the responses as new!

Yes, of course! That was what I meant with "it would be a little trickier to track down the responses" --> if there were hundreds or thousands of responses and months of editing, it would be quite complex to accomplish that; but of course, it's an option!
